# isPalindrome function in Haskell gives an error

Tags: haskell, palindrome

I was trying to write a program that checks whether a list is palindrome and returns Bool.

```
isPalindrome :: [a] -> Bool
isPalindrome [] = True
isPalindrome [x] = True
isPalindrome xs | (head xs) == (last xs) = isPalindrome (init(tail xs))
                | otherwise = False
```

And I recieved an error message like this:

```
problem6.hs:4:19: error:
    * No instance for (Eq a) arising from a use of `=='
      Possible fix:
        add (Eq a) to the context of
          the type signature for:
            isPalindrome :: forall a. [a] -> Bool
    * In the expression: (head xs) == (last xs)
      In a stmt of a pattern guard for
                     an equation for `isPalindrome':
        (head xs) == (last xs)
      In an equation for `isPalindrome':
          isPalindrome xs
            | (head xs) == (last xs) = isPalindrome (init (tail xs))
            | otherwise = False
  |
4 | isPalindrome xs | (head xs) == (last xs) = isPalindrome (init(tail xs))
  |                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Failed, no modules loaded.
```

Because I am not very experienced, I don't understand a thing from error message. So I don't see where the mistake is in my code. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is you need to constrain the polymorphic type `a`. Right now, the compiler has no information about the type, so it can't even know if `(==)` is defined for `a` (this is where the ``` No instance for (Eq a) arising from a use of ``==' ``` comes from. It is trying to infer an instance of `Eq` for `a`, but it is unable to. You need to help it along).

You should make the type:

```
isPalindrome :: (Eq a) => [a] -> Bool
```

Now you're telling it that `isPalindrome` can only be given lists of things that are instances of `Eq`.

It points out this piece because your are trying to compare two `a`'s for equality:

```
(head xs) == (last xs)
```

A little bit about the error message:

```
 Possible fix:
    add (Eq a) to the context of
      the type signature for:
        isPalindrome :: forall a. [a] -> Bool
```

The stuff before the `=>` in my suggestion is called the context, and it is where you can add constraints to your types. The suggestion here is telling you to do exactly what I said above (albeit in a much more verbose way).

Comment: So, do you mean when I don't write (Eq a) => the compiler doesn't have any assumption about typeclass of a?

Comment: Correct. All it knows is there is some time `a`, it knows nothing else about the type. You need to tell it what is safe to assume. This is so it can enforce the required instance at the call site.

Comment: @Piamoon if you would've omitted the type signature, GHC would've inferred the correct type, with the constraint. But user-supplied signature takes precedence, and it disagrees (says there's no `Eq` constraint) with the inferred type (which says there must be the `Eq` constraint). Unable to follow your command, the compiler errors out. It assumes the user knew what they were doing supplying that signature.

Answer (score 0):

```
import Data.List

isPalindrome :: (Eq a) => [a] -> Bool
isPalindrome [] = True
isPalindrome [x] = True
isPalindrome xs    
                | (head xs /= head (reverse xs)) = False
                | otherwise = isPalindrome ( tail (init xs) )
```